# Laravel auth middleware not working to download jpeg

Tags: php, laravel-5, middleware

First, it happens only in production, I'm using Cloudways with laravel stack (debian + nginx + apache + mysql).

In my local environment, everything works fine.

Every time I try to open the URL with the right parameters I got redirected to home/login, like if the middlewere had rejected.

The URL was supposed to download my image.

Routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('image/{name}', 'FileController@getImage');
```

Controller/FileController.php:

```
class FileController extends Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        // if I comment this line, it works in production too, but I can download content without being logged in... 
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function getImage($name)
    {
        return response()->download(storage_path('app/images/' . $name), null, [], null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably your session is not set, that is why. Double check you are logged in. Since you said it works in your local machine, but not in your server, try deleting your cache and refresh your autoload with `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dumpautoload` respectively in your production server.

Comment: Is there any difference between the two configurations files? Is your session management correctly configured on production?

Comment: I don't think that's something related to session, because I've other controllers using the auth middleware too. And they're working fine.

Comment: Make sure the group your web server is running as (usually www-data or nginx) has the correct permissions to read the folder and files from app/images/ and can access the folder you have your project in. Permissions have given me lots of trouble in the past. This sounds like this might be the problem for you as well. If that is the case, `chmod` will be your best friend :)